# Blue Prism Server Can Not See Runtime Resources

Tags: server, blueprism

I can not get Scheduler to work. I can run processes using interactive clients, but I don't see them as available when I run the interactive client on the server. They all show as offline yet I know they are running. This means that Scheduler can not start any process. Can anyone help with this? Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted specifically what you have tried, and the error messages if you are getting any.

Comment: There are a number of possible reasons for this, but it's most likely that there's a firewall or firewall-like device between the two components that's blocking the communication between them

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's due to the subsystem not being exposed under server group but instead under the managed server. Try changing the descriptor for the runtime service resource type to declare, so that it also runs inside managed server; might fix this issue if the runtime subsystem is correctly discovered and becomes available under the managed server.